# Get messages that were sent in the last 7 days (Applescript)

Tags: applescript, mail.app

As part of my routine, I review all outgoing emails once every week to see if any of them need to be flagged for follow-up. I want to try a different approach and instead of going through my Sent Mail, automatically send myself an email every week that lists all emails sent in the preceding week.

I wrote an AppleScript that does this, but it contains an inefficiency that I'd like to remove.

```
repeat with myMessage in items 1 through theHorizon of (get messages of myMailbox)              
if (currentDate - (date sent of myMessage)) div days is less than theTimeframe then
```

As my Sent Mail has tens of thousands of messages, I make the script only consider the first 350 messages (`theHorizon`). This should be enough, but I don't really know. To confirm the message was indeed sent within the last 7 days, I run every message through an `if` statement.

What I would like, however, is for the `repeat` statement to read something like this

```
repeat with myMessage in (get messages of myMailbox where date sent is less than 7 days ago)
```

This obviously doesn't work, I've tried a bunch of different formats but nothing seems to be working properly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's absolutely possible.  Here's an example using my IMAP mail account, the name of which I've redacted for personal privacy:

```
    tell application "Mail" to get the subject of ¬
        every message of mailbox "Sent" of ¬
        account "C*************.com" whose ¬
        date sent > ((current date) - days * 3)
```

This returns a list containing the subjects of each mail message that I sent within the last 3 days.

To apply this to your specific situation, you create a command that resembles this:

```
    tell application "Mail" to repeat with myMessage in (the ¬
        messages of mailbox MySentMailbox of ¬
        account MyAccount whose ¬
        date sent > ((current date) - days * 7))
            .
            .
            .
    end repeat
```